# iOS App Store shows wrong version number for my app

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have a new app update that shows version number 2.5, but when you tap the app for more details and check the Information section the version number is still 2.4.2.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is simply caching, Apple serving the same information to clients over time so as not to put additional strain on their database. I see this every time I update one of my apps.

It'll fix itself in several hours, perhaps a day at most.